# Insert a cell will not update the insetForSectionAtIndex

Tags: ios, swift

Insert a cell to collection with :

```
 let index = data.count-1
            let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: index, inSection: 0)
            collectionView.insertItemsAtIndexPaths([indexPath])
```

Works but will not call this delegate on update :

```
 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
```

Why I need this one ?  because I align the cells according to an index, so a new cell most be align properly (left/right) when inserted .

Is there away to call it on insert? (don't want to deal with positions inside `cellForItemAtIndexPath`)

Answer (score 0):

No, the delegate method you memtioned only gets called for secions, not for cells.

You could align your UI element inside cells, rather than align the cell itself.

Comment: It seems like not a proper thing to do, align views inside cells. I want to determine a cell position, not creating a patch